# Multiple Ajax Queries on Ready Function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, document-ready, onload-event

I have a table something like the below image
[image]

I want to fill in the "ROL" column with data after the page is loaded via `jquery .get method`

To do that I am using the below mentioned code

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.details').each(function() {
            locid = $(this).find('.locationId').html();
            prodid = $(this).find('.productId').html();
            alert(prodid);
            roqty = $(this).find('.roqty');

            $.get('myUrl', null, function(d) {
                CC = JSON.parse(d);
                roqty.html(CC.roqty);
            });
        });
    }, 5000);
})
```

After the page is loaded only the last cell of ROL column is get filled. Please see the below image.

[image]

Although the `alert` is happening 3 times.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have defined `roqty`  as Global variable it's reference is updated to last element while waiting for `$.get('myUrl')` to complete.

Define `roqty` as  local variable scoped to `each()` callback function.

```
var roqty = $(this).find('.roqty');
```

Comment: Perfect this worked. Accepting your answer in few mins.

Comment: just curious, why then in alert the prodid was coming proper, whereas it was also defined as global?Thanks.

Comment: @abbas, You have specified `alert(prodid);` in the callback of `$.each` not `$.get('myUrl'`